# Is it possible to subclass a Java object in the constructor?

Tags: java, constructor, selenium-webdriver, subclassing

Is it possible to subclass a Java object in the constructor?

I am a Java newbie trying out Selenium in an article here http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions there is a note about how to modify an HtmlUnitDriver driver object to support authentication with some demo code I have repeated here.

```
WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver() {
  protected WebClient modifyWebClient(WebClient client) {
    // This class ships with HtmlUnit itself
    DefaultCredentialsProvider creds = DefaultCredentialsProvider();

    // Set some example credentials
    creds.addCredentials("username", "password");

    // And now add the provider to the webClient instance
    client.setCredentialsProvider(creds);

    return client;
  }
};
```

Is the code an example that goes into the definition of subclass or is it a modification that is 'inline'? I have assumed that it is possible but when I copy it into the IDE I get syntax errors showing that some of the properties are not defined.

After learning more about Java, anonymous classes and overrides this is my current code.
But I am getting a syntax error on the DefaultCredentialsProvider in Netbeans, and I am not sure whether it is due to the absence of required classes, or whether some more changes are required.

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package seleniumtest01;

/**
 *
 * @author richard
 */
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCredentialsProvider;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
//import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.ChromeDriver;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Create a new instance of the Firefox driver
    // Notice that the remainder of the code relies on the interface,
    // not the implementation.
    testBasicAuth();
    System.exit(0);
  }

  public static void testBasicAuth() {
    // Create a new instance of the Firefox driver
    // Notice that the remainder of the code relies on the interface,
    // not the implementation.
    //WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver() {

      @Override
      protected WebClient modifyWebClient(WebClient client) {
        // This class ships with HtmlUnit itself
        DefaultCredentialsProvider creds = DefaultCredentialsProvider();

        // Set some example credentials
        creds.addCredentials("username", "password");

        // And now add the provider to the webClient instance
        client.setCredentialsProvider(creds);

        return client;
      }
    };
    driver.get("http://user:selenium@192.168.1.2/");
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Connection']"));
    element.click();
    //element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Admin Login']"));
    element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href, 'admin/connection')]"));//[contains(@href,'#id1')]
    element.click();
    element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Connection 1']"));
    element.click();
    element = driver.findElement(By.name("field_one"));
    element.clear();
    element.sendKeys("sample text");
    //driver.findElement(By. id("submit")).click();
    element.submit();

    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    driver.quit();
  }


}
```

Comment: If you declare something as protected you might be forgetting @Override?

Comment: I'm new to Java and learning the Java view on subclasses, anonymous claasses etc, the @override has shown up in Netbeans so I am looking it up now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After posting the question on sqa.stackexchange.com I got this is what the constructor for the WebDriver should be:

```
WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver() {

  @Override
  protected WebClient modifyWebClient(WebClient client) {
    // This class ships with HtmlUnit itself
    DefaultCredentialsProvider creds = new DefaultCredentialsProvider();

    // Set some example credentials
    creds.addCredentials("user", "selenium");

    // And now add the provider to the webClient instance
    client.setCredentialsProvider(creds);

    return client;
  }
};
```

After adding the override I was missing the `new` to the creds initialization, a Java newbie error.
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

The code you presented is not modifying the original class, but is creating an anonymous subclass of `HtmlUnitDriver`.

For example:

```
class A {
  void sayHello() { System.out.println("Hello!"); }
}

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    A a = new A() {
      @Override void sayHello() { System.out.println("Good bye"); }
    }

    a.sayHello();
  }
}
```

This will print `Good bye`. The type of the instance held by the local variable `a` is an anonymous class, automatically generated by the compiler. The name of the class will be something like `Main$0`.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to give a clear answer to this question without having the Javadoc of the class `HtmlUnitDriver`. If `HtmlUnitDriver` is an abstract class or an interface, then the sample code in your question is called an anonymous class. Otherwise, the code is simply overriding the method of the class.